# Can you create feature classes with the same name in different feature dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, feature-dataset

I've searched but can't seem to find any info on this which is surprising as this should be an easy one to answer.

I'm using ArcGIS 9.3 and trying to create a feature class called 'cadastre' in multiple feature datasets within the same file geodatabase.

ArcCatalog is giving me a 'The specified name already exists.  Please enter a different name' error.

It's been a while since I used ESRI software but I would have imagined this was possible since they are in seperate feature datasets.

Is this expected funcitonality of the geodatabase?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First answer - No, you can not have duplicate names in a geodatabase.
Yes, this is the expected functionality since the Feature-Dataset is only a record reference in a database. Any database will balk at having tables with duplicate names. It sounds like you are trying to use the Feature-Dataset model for organizational purposes versus the true purpose of it.
Many users will try to use them as folders for grouping data; versus the intent which is to inter-relate data via topology and relationship rules.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I thought perhaps that internally the table name would be stored with a reference to the Feature-Dataset.

Comment: It is; but the general rules of the database still exist in that the parent datastore is just a list of tables that talk about the tables.

Comment: A feature datasets [_"primary purpose is for organizing related feature classes into a common dataset for building a topology, a network dataset, a terrain dataset, or a geometric network."_](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/an_overv518725971.htm)

Comment: Also see: [Is there a performance hit from using a Feature Dataset?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11537/is-there-a-performance-hit-from-using-a-feature-dataset)

Comment: Very true Ryan; there is also the constraint on table/feature locking when using Feature Datasets when it comes to editing.

Comment: Went back to the client and sorted out a new Geodatabase structure.  The new structure is messy by comparison.  I think it would be nice if a feature datasets 'secondary purpose' was to organise your data into a logical structure.  It could still store the table names as different names, just add an unique id to the feature dataset and use this to build the unique table name.  Then display the table to the end user minus the unique id.

Comment: That is a good suggestion, you might submit it to ESRI in ideas.arcgis.com, but that would leave you a split view where ESRI would should you one view of data, while the RAW RDBMS would show the core/root tables with what I think you would see as a Aliased structure. While I agree with what you say, I think in the long run that this could be complicated to manage for some classes of users.

Answer (score 1):

From the **[ArcGIS Server 9.3 Help](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisserver/9.3/java/index.htm#geodatabases/definin-643225741.htm)**:

“Feature class names must be unique in a geodatabase—you can't have more than one feature class with the same name. This is true of all feature classes in the same geodatabase, even those grouped with other feature classes in a feature dataset.”